# Android webview does not display Javascript Append

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

I'm using webview for my Android application, I'm getting my php, html files from my server online. The problem is, when I try it in my desktop browser, it's displaying the appended text, but when I try it on my Android phone, it's not displaying.

Please note that Javascipt is enabled in my webview's settings. I also use JQuery Mobile plugin.

Code:

```
function loadMore()
{
    $('#htmlDivID').append("HELLO WORLD.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery mobile:

```
function loadMore(){
   $('#htmlDivID').append("HELLO WORLD.");
}
$(document).on('pageinit', function(event){
  loadMore();
});
```

from docs:

> Triggered on the page being initialized, after initialization occurs. We recommend binding to this event instead of DOM ready() because this will work regardless of whether the page is loaded directly or if the content is pulled into another page as part of the Ajax navigation system.

Comment: I actually trigger `loadMore()` function using a Jquery Mobile button. But I will try this. Thanks.